# How do I update label timer inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I have a label timer inside a `UITableViewCell`, using this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

    timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 26, 280, 25)];
    timeLabel.text = [timeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];
    return cell;
    NSLog(@"Title %@, time %@, second %@, time %i, tag %d", titleArray, timeArray, secondArray, time, button.tag);
}
```

And I have a timer that trigger by a button using this code

```
- (void)onoffBtn:(id)sender
{
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerElapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) timerElapsed:(id)timer
{
    if (time == 0)
    {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
    }
    // this part only code for counting down timer
    NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d", hour , minute, second);
}
```

If I put `timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", hour , minute, second];` inside `timerElapsed`, of course it wont update my label inside cell.

So how do I update my label inside cell for every second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", hour , minute, second];` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and call `reloadData` method of your tableview inside timerElapsed.

I believe your hour, minute and second contain updated value.

Comment: yes, you both is right for 1 cell but isnt right if cells more than 1. the label only update for las cell only.

Comment: If your each cell contain different hour , minute, second values then you should use array which will contain value for each cell and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you should provide values from array as [hourArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] and so on..where hourArr is an array Got it? You should be clear while asking question.

Answer (score 2):

You can update your table with this:

```
[theTable reloadData]
```

make sure reloading then gets the correct values when rebuilding your cells of the table

EDIT:
do not forget to recycle the cells like this...

```
        static NSString *kDisplayCell_ID = @"DisplayCellID";
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDisplayCell_ID];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kDisplayCell_ID];
        }
         ....
```

You might want to check how

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

needs to be implemented

Comment: please check the answer - it looks as if you forgot to recycle the cells